# iOS Watch OS 2 with Xcode 7 Beta 4.0 AppWatch Launching App with Activity Indicator Screen Only

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, xcode7-beta4

I am developing the iOS watchApp with WatchDevice.
I have facing issues with Running the app in the Real device.
Its keep on showing only ActivityIndicator and nothing goes ahead of this screen.even i tested with Hello world Test App.
By just putting One Static Label,but its still showing same activityIndicator.Anyone knows how to solve this issue??any thing Wrong with My Code or setup?

Comment: This was a known bug in Xcode 7 Beta 4, and it meant that real watch devices wouldn't install your app properly most of the time - Beta 5 has made some changes to try and resolve these issues so you should probably check that out. Also take a look at the change-log so you know whats going on: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_5/Xcode_7_beta_5_Release_Notes.pdf